# Why does my HP Pavillion 15- notebook not see my docking station with a 4T WD Red Plus? Smaller 2T drives are recognised

Tags: hard-drive, hp, docking, help

I have been reading from this site as well as others trying to understand this. It all started with this tiny 500 SSD with a dream to make this notebook's capacity something one can do something with. So I bought a new WD Red Plus 4 T, already had a USB 2.0 Black X 5G single 3.5" SATA docking station that I had been using for an older PC. It works fine for this 2yr old HP when using smaller drives, eg. Seagate 500 and 2T drives. However, the HP will not bite when it comes to the 4T. Recent UC grad Computer Systems son has been trying to help. What we have found so far is that the drive is alive and well when connected to his PC using the normal connections. His PC will see the drive as connected with the docking system on occasion. At first we suspected it was a USB 2.0 limitation, then we thought it was a limitation on the docking system itself. Reading the posts on Stack Xchange took care of those theories. I did order a yet to arrive docking system USB 3.0, if for no other reason to speed up the transfer once everything somehow got to the copacetic phase.
Anything else we can try? Thank-you Dan-ger

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not enough information here to base an opinion.

Comment: Welcome. Please consider rephrasing your question to be more specific and precise. Much of the text you've entered is "conversational", stories and not related specifically to your issue, and they distract and detract from your question. Focus on a clear and precise description of your problem, research you have done, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: ... and hardware specifications... Instead of an unnamed docking station that probably is just an USB enclosure you should've posted the the actual brand/model. And yes, very likely the "SATA-to-USB" controller (chipset) is the limiting factor, totally expected for an old USB 2.0 enclosure as they typically were capped at 2TB drives.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The un named docking station that I wrote as a Black X 5G 2.0 is what was written on the case. It was a single slot, so I just said single. Sorry for not being clear. Looks like I do converse, so can't argue that. I am just a simple man out of my depth on most things. I went down to Central Computer in SJ; they put my system of docking on their PC and got some of the 4 T to come up. Still waiting for my new docking station, now it's tomorrow, Fed _Ex claims. So next time I will take these hints and pieces of advice given and DO BETTER.

Comment: Thanks to all who pointed out the docking station as the likely culprit. Received the "WAVLINK USB 3.0 to Dual Bay SATA Adapter, External 2.5" 3.5'' SATA Hard Drive Connector with 2 USB3.0 Ports and Offline Cloning Function for Files Transfer & Backup (2x18 TB & UASP Supported)", and things are good. Peace out, Dan-ger